# How to prevent VS Code to remember terminal sessions

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

New version of VS Code started restoring Terminal sessions from the last time it was used. How to override that behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This config in `settings.json` solved it:

```json
"terminal.integrated.persistentSessionReviveProcess": "never"
```

Answer (score 16):

So your settings are visible in JSON or UI format. For JSON @Nenad Milosavljevic solution should do the job.
I'll explain the UI one.

1. Open command palette (CTRL + SHIFT + P)
2. Type user settings and select the option
   [image: Command paletter navigation]
3. Select Features > Terminal > scroll down a little where you'll find the option and then uncheck the option "Integrated: Enable Persistent Sessions"
   [image: Settings option]

4. Close the tab and you're done.

Answer (score 9):

Disable this setting:

`Terminal > Integrated: Enable Persistent Sessions`

It is enabled by default.

Comment: I can not find that option.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of vscode?

Comment: I am using `v1.62.0`. I managed to solve it with a config in `settings.json`.

Comment: Open the Settings UI (Gear Icon/Settings), there search for "sessions".  Disable - uncheck - the `Enable Persistent Sessions`  setting.